# [pandas]: most performant way to create foreign keys from one table to another?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, multiprocessing

i'm working on a very large dataset (4M rows) to transform CSV files to SQL. i need to create joins between several dataframes, using the index of a table as the foreign key to another table. i've found a solution which is quite slow (1800 rows/s, see below), and ***i'm looking for a faster (more performant) way.***

#### what's the fastest way to create joins between the two following dataframes? (replace `df1.street` by `df2.index` where `df1.street == df2.street` and `df1.number == df2.number`)

i'm open to any solutions, including multiprocessing (tried it, but no luck at it) as long as it makes things go faster, using as little memory as possible. i've also tried `df.merge()` and other functions, but no luck so far.

***thanks !!!***

---

## dataframes

#### df1

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'street': {'qr16ef3677886a44f8b9c5bc37dd660688a': 'quai de la Tournelle', 'qr112e28085e3c84c41b6b6a5e13ecf15ac': 'r. AlexandreDumas', 'qr1a213d2a5cbf64718892b3dbb3a9024f1': 'pass. Brunoy', 'qr1fb0760cd0fab4c71a4297d006ec3d119': 'Montmartre', 'qr167fce4c23d5c4b879ca6423cea15e742': 'Martel'}
    , 'number': {'qr16ef3677886a44f8b9c5bc37dd660688a': '33', 'qr112e28085e3c84c41b6b6a5e13ecf15ac': '99', 'qr1a213d2a5cbf64718892b3dbb3a9024f1': '18', 'qr1fb0760cd0fab4c71a4297d006ec3d119': '123', 'qr167fce4c23d5c4b879ca6423cea15e742': '4'}
    , 'date': {'qr16ef3677886a44f8b9c5bc37dd660688a': 1914, 'qr112e28085e3c84c41b6b6a5e13ecf15ac': 1900, 'qr1a213d2a5cbf64718892b3dbb3a9024f1': 1921, 'qr1fb0760cd0fab4c71a4297d006ec3d119': 1858, 'qr167fce4c23d5c4b879ca6423cea15e742': 1896}
})
```

```
                                                    street number  date
qr16ef3677886a44f8b9c5bc37dd660688a  quai de la Tournelle     33  1914
qr112e28085e3c84c41b6b6a5e13ecf15ac     r. AlexandreDumas     99  1900
qr1a213d2a5cbf64718892b3dbb3a9024f1          pass. Brunoy     18  1921
qr1fb0760cd0fab4c71a4297d006ec3d119            Montmartre    123  1858
qr167fce4c23d5c4b879ca6423cea15e742                Martel      4  1896
```

#### df2

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'number': {'qr152f8de48daa64cf098f44fb3d9e7e145': '123', 'qr18ae0099b6afb48a78d466e5ed6871bec': '18', 'qr183daee61fb98489ebd05556968027a0d': '18', 'qr1e0ee6ec37dbd4e799905db721592ba48': '33', 'qr148505eca183c4fb38f844c35130b92f0': '4'}
    , 'street': {'qr152f8de48daa64cf098f44fb3d9e7e145': 'Montmartre', 'qr18ae0099b6afb48a78d466e5ed6871bec': 'Montmartre', 'qr183daee61fb98489ebd05556968027a0d': 'pass. Brunoy', 'qr1e0ee6ec37dbd4e799905db721592ba48': 'quai de la Tournelle', 'qr148505eca183c4fb38f844c35130b92f0': 'Martel'}
    , 'date': {'qr152f8de48daa64cf098f44fb3d9e7e145': ['1858', '1858'], 'qr18ae0099b6afb48a78d466e5ed6871bec': ['1876', '1881'], 'qr183daee61fb98489ebd05556968027a0d': ['1921', '1921'], 'qr1e0ee6ec37dbd4e799905db721592ba48': ['1914', '1914'], 'qr148505eca183c4fb38f844c35130b92f0': ['1896', '1896']}
})
```

```
                                     number                street          date
qr152f8de48daa64cf098f44fb3d9e7e145    123            Montmartre  [1858, 1858]
qr18ae0099b6afb48a78d466e5ed6871bec     18            Montmartre  [1876, 1881]
qr183daee61fb98489ebd05556968027a0d     18          pass. Brunoy  [1921, 1921]
qr1e0ee6ec37dbd4e799905db721592ba48     33  quai de la Tournelle  [1914, 1914]
qr148505eca183c4fb38f844c35130b92f0      4                Martel  [1896, 1896]
```

---

### my solution

my solution relies on using a function (`foreignkey()`) called inside a `df.apply()`. however, `df.apply()` is supposed to be slower than other methods, and my solution comes dangerously close to doing a double loop, on `df1` and `df2`

```py
def foreignkey(ro: pd.core.series.Series) -> pd.core.series.Series:
    """
    replace the address in `ro` of `df1` by a foreign key 
    pointing to `df2`. the key is inserted in `ro.name`
    """
    ro.street = df2.loc[
        ( df2.street == ro.street )    # address has the same street full name
        & ( df2.number == ro.number )  # address has the same street number
    ].index[0]
    return ro

df1 = df1.progress_apply( lambda x: foreignkey(x), axis=1 )
```

Comment: I suggest going into **numpy** domain (`df.values`), use vectorized functions of numpy, if really needed write simple python loops and use **numba** to vectorize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you described is a classic `merge` operation (it's called `JOIN` in the SQL world).

Try this to see if it speeds up your code:

```py
tmp = (
    df1.reset_index(names="df1_id")
    .merge(
        df2[["street", "number"]].reset_index(names="df2_id"),
        how="left",
        on=["street", "number"],
    )
    .drop_duplicates("df1_id")
    .set_index("df1_id")
)
df1["street_id"] = tmp["df2_id"]
```

The `drop_duplicates` is there to keep only the first match when one row in `df1` matches multiple rows in `df2`.

Comment: thank you so much ! i didn't know how to perform the `df.merge()`. there is indeed a huge performance gain: my method takes `2.50137` seconds to complete, yours takes only `0.00504` seconds on `4406` rows in `df1`.